# After updating Symfony from 5.4 to 6.4 routing.yml stoped working

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I have a project legacy that I have been updating since symfony 2. Now I am at 6.4 however my routes stoped working.

In my routing.yml i am trying to fix the routes in the Admin folder.
Following the documentation https://symfony.com/doc/6.4/routing/custom_route_loader.html
but is not working.

I have tried:

```
app_admin:
  resource: ../../src/AppBundle/Controller/Admin/
  type: attribute
```

And the error is:

```
In FileLoader.php line 182:
                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  Warning: Array to string conversion in app/config/../../src/AppBundle/Controller/Admin/ (which is being imported from app/config/routing.yml"). Make sure there is a loader supporting the "attribute" type.                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

In AttributeClassLoader.php line 219:
                                       
  Warning: Array to string conversion
```

I also have tried:

```
app_admin:
  # loads routes from the PHP attributes of the controllers found in the given PSR-4 namespace root
  resource:
    path: '../../src/AppBundle/Controller/Admin/'
    namespace: App\Controller\Admin
  type: attribute
```

However the $ php bin/console debug:router
does not load any routes.

[image]

If I change the routing.yml to add each class it works, but I don't think it is the best way to do it. Adding each class is going to be a pain.

[image]

AdminController

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller\Admin;


use AppBundle\Service\SmsMailer;
use AppBundle\Entity\CletClient;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Mailer\MailerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Notifier\TexterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class AdminController extends AbstractController
{

    #[Route(path: '/admin/', name: 'admin')]
    public function showAction(){

        return $this->render("@App/admin/show.html.twig", array(
            '' => '',
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/admin/sales-chart/", options={"expose"=true},name="sales_chart_data")
     */
    public function getSalesChartDataAction(){


        $json = '{}';
        $result = json_decode ($json);
        return new Response(json_encode($result));

    }

    /**
     * @Route("/file_manager/", name="file_manager")
     */
    public function fileManager(){

        return $this->render("@App/admin/blank.html.twig", array(
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/2fa_email/", name="two_factor_email")
     */
    public function twoFactorEmail(MailerInterface $mailer, TexterInterface $texter){

        return $this->redirectToRoute("2fa_login");
    }
}
```

Anyone have a clue what I am missing?

Comment: shouldn't it be `path: '../src/AppBundle/Controller/Admin/'`

Comment: It looks like you have a problem with attributes. Could you share the `AdminController.php` file with us?

Comment: @craigh 
Does not make any difference. If I change the way you suggested same result as the first image above

Comment: @AlexandreTranchant

I have just updated the comment and AdminController is there.

Comment: You could try out Rector (https://github.com/rectorphp/rector) it scans your code and determines what need to be changed when upgrading a framework. It's extremely useful for your situation. 
Also always make sure you fix all deprecation errors before upgrading the symfony framework. Symfony always adds deprecation logs which you need to fix first. Each upgrade also comes with a guide you could check https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/upgrade_major.html

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. For me the solution was to replace the Symfony 5.4 `Kernel.php` file in `src` folder with one of a fresh Symfony 6.4 install :

Just run the following : `composer create-project symfony/skeleton:"6.4.*" symfony6`

Then, in your newly created `symfony6` project, you should find in the `src` folder a Kernel.php file looking like this :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Kernel\MicroKernelTrait;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel as BaseKernel;

class Kernel extends BaseKernel
{
    use MicroKernelTrait;
}
```

Also, I am not 100% sure about that as I could not find any confirmation in the Symfony documentation, but I think the old Routes annotation is no longer supported and native PHP 8 attributes notation should be used instead, like you started to do so with the `admin` route.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you @Saitama, My project already have the same file Kernel as yours. However my project uses AppKernel.php in app/AppKernel.php. 
So I am really not sure what would be, any idea?

Comment: AppKernel.php has been renamed to Kernel.php (and placed in the src folder) since Symfony 4. If your application was firstly built in Symfony 3, maybe you have to adapt its file structure to Symfony 4+ standards ?  Symfony core is doing a lot of stuff to detect files, classes, injections automatically. I can imagine it to expect ist new standard structure to be respected in order to find files in it. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I've identified the issue. Many of my routes include parameters that are no longer supported, such as 'options' and 'requirements.' Once these were removed, the routes were successfully restored.

For example:

```
/**
 * @Route("", name="", options={"expose"=true}, requirements={"_format" = "xml"})
*/
```

By updating and eliminating the outdated parameters, we were able to resolve the problem.

Ps: I still need to change all annotation to attribute